# RecyclerView DiffUtil need to update the data manually？

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-diffutils

now I find a bug in my project

```
val diffCallback = diff.newInstance(list, newList)
val diffResult = DiffUtil.calculateDiff(diffCallback)
list.clear()
list.addAll(newList)
diffResult.dispatchUpdatesTo(this)
```

this is my diff code in my adapter, you can see I clear old list and update the new list.

but I use data in viewholder and set tag with it in a view.

when I set old data as a tag in a view, then I diff the list, because as this diffUtil return true, so view also handler old data in his tag, but I always update adapter list when diff, so when I use `adapter.list.getindex(data)` I get -1 because view tag is old data, and my adapter list had to update new list, Even if the old list data view == new list.

when I remove `list.clear() list.addAll(newList)`, the diff cannot succeed,
someone can tell me why? and how can I solve this problem?